# How to pass element object instead of id in JSXGraph?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jsxgraph

I'm trying to change

```
var brd2 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-8.75, 2.5, 8.75, -2.5]});
```

as

```
var brd2 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard(this.$('#box'), {boundingbox: [-8.75, 2.5, 8.75, -2.5]});
```

Since dynamic elements are created inside backbone views, I need to initialize JSXGraph for each element with the id "box".

Answer (score 0):

With the following hack it is possible to pass the object instead of the id to JSXGraph. First you need an invisible div with e.g. the id "dummy". Then the board is initialised with this dummy id and we have to make corrections afterwards. Let's further assume that

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('dummy', {axis:false,
    boundingbox: [-10,30,10,-10], keepaspectratio:false});

var obj = document.getElementById('box'); // or this.$('#box')

board.removeEventHandlers();
board.container = 'box';
board.containerObj = obj;
//
// Supply the dimensions of the box
board.renderer = new JXG.SVGRenderer(obj, {width: 800, height: 800});
board.setBoundingBox([-10,30,10,-10], false);
board.addEventHandlers();
```

Please note, that specifying *axis:true* or *grid:true* in initBoard() will not work.

Hope that helps,
Alfred